# c# .net datagridview SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm racking my head over something that should be pretty simple to do. Its been a day now so I finally give up and I will ask the question. How can I actually trigger the selectionChanged event on the datagridview in .net?
I would basically like to grab the row values when the user double-clicks/ or single clicks any where on a row. but I cant for the life of me get this event to fire even tough I read here that this should be the even I need to use?

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in AddrGrid.SelectedRows)
            {
                string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //...
            }
        }
```

I have tried something similar to this but im hopeless I click on the datagrid cells or rows and this does not fire what I'm I missing?

when I click on a cell I get this event to fire.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            Addresses.aTyp = AddrGrid.Rows[AddrGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Address Type"].Value.ToString();
            Addresses.seq  =  AddrGrid.Rows[AddrGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Sequence"].Value.ToString();

        }
```

But I  like to capture the double click or click on a row not just a cell.
Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you hooking the event handler up?

Comment: i'm pretty new to the event handling throw me a bone and tell me how to hook it up please.

Comment: what is AddrGrid this looks to be the issue.. I will post what it should look like

Comment: What are you wanting to do exactly in this Event dataGridView1_CellContentClick

Comment: im trying to select a few values from the grid and then close the form that the grid is displaying on.

Comment: What do you have set in the property window for DataGridView's MultiSelect property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your grid object lets call it 'foo'.  You will do something like..

```
foo.SelectionChanged += dataGridView1_SelectionChanged
```

you will need to do that somewhere to wire the event up. I normally do it in the constructor for the form

Comment: @MarkHall Good call, I always forget that option is there

Comment: I feel like such an idiot this is what I was trying to do ! thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) 
     {
        string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
    private void AddrGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        Addresses.aTyp = AddrGrid.Rows[AddrGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Address Type"].Value.ToString();
        Addresses.seq = AddrGrid.Rows[AddrGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Sequence"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many answers relating to the selectionchanged  event for a DataGridview use "**DG1.SelectedRows(0)**". This is fundementally wrong. There may be multiple rows selected and the first selected row may not be the newly selected row. Unless you want to parse over all of the selected rows each time, "**DG1.Rows(DG1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)**"  should be used